# Pytorch - compute accuracy UNet multi-class segmentation

Tags: python, pytorch, metrics, image-segmentation, unet-neural-network

I'm trying to run on pytorch a UNet model for a multi-class image segmentation. I found an architecture of the model online that is apparently working ... I have 100 classes, my input is corresponding to a tensor size [8, 3, 32, 32], my label is [8, 32, 32] and as expected my output is [8, 100, 32, 32].

I want to compute the accuracy for every iteration so I followed this code for the computation of the accuracy :

```
def multi_acc(pred, label):
    probs = torch.log_softmax(pred, dim = 1)
    _, tags = torch.max(probs, dim = 1)
    corrects = (tags == label).float()
    acc = corrects.sum()/len(corrects)
    acc = torch.round(acc)*100
    return acc
```

But then when i'm running the training i get an accuracy that is always the same as :

```
 Epoch : [2] [1/38311] Loss : 0.3168763518333435
 Acc: 102400.0
 Epoch : [2] [2/38311] Loss : 0.31527179479599
 Acc: 102400.0
 Epoch : [2] [3/38311] Loss : 0.2920961081981659
 Acc: 102400.0
```

And it keep going like this...
If anyone has an idea to better understand that would be super great !

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this is the issue but the `==` operator stands out to me as a possible source of error. This operator is not necessarily implemented in the way you suspect it is for n-dimensional tensor objects. Instead try `torch.where()`

Answer (score 0):

`corrects` is a 3-dimensional array (batch, wdith, height) or something like that. When you call `acc = corrects.sum() / len(corrects)`, `len` returns the size of the **first dimension** of the tensor, in this case 8 I think. Instead use `.numel()` to return the total number of elements in the 3-dimensional tensor. Also I recommend using `torch.eq()`. Also, don't round at the end. acc should be between 0 and 1 before rounding so if round it you'll always either get 0 or 1, which will correspond to 0 or 100 % accuracy after converting to percentage. Leave your accuracy metric unrounded and round it when you print it.

```
def multi_acc(pred, label):
    probs = torch.log_softmax(pred, dim = 1)
    _, tags = torch.max(probs, dim = 1)
    corrects = torch.eq(tags,label).int()
    acc = corrects.sum()/corrects.numel()
    return acc
```

Answer (score 0):

You calculate the accuracy with:

```py
acc = corrects.sum()/len(corrects)
```

`corrects` has a size of `torch.Size([8, 32, 32])`, taking the sum with `corrects.sum()` gives you the number of correctly classified pixels, and there are a total of `8 * 32 * 32 = 8192`. The accuracy should be `num_correct / num_total`, but you're dividing it by `len(corrects) == 8`. To get the total number of elements you can use [`torch.numel`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.numel).

Another problem is that you're rounding your accuracy:

```py
acc = torch.round(acc)*100
```

The accuracy is a value between 0 and 1. By rounding it, you'll get 0 for everything below 0.5 and 1 for everything else. That means you would only determine whether you've achieved over 50% accuracy. You need to remove the rounding entirely.

Applying these changes, you get the following function. I also removed the `log_softmax`, which leaves the order unchanged (larger values have larger probabilities). Since you're not using the probabilities, it has no effect:

```py
def multi_acc(pred, label):
    _, tags = torch.max(pred, dim = 1)
    corrects = (tags == label).float()
    acc = corrects.sum() / corrects.numel()
    acc = acc * 100
    return acc
```

Comment: Thanks ! I think it works now :) Now I have to solve the problem that my model converge really fast in my point of view...